# Fundamental question! (HD Wallet private key hacked)

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, mnemonic

What is the probability of the mnemonic or privatekey of the HD wallet being hacked?

1. It is being used as a wallet created by metamask.
2. The user is using a wallet with a private key backed up by Metamask for a 100% decentralized application.
3. The user stores the keystore file on the phone/computer by backing up the keystore file provided by the decentralized app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Guessing private keys](https://www.wired.com/story/blockchain-bandit-ethereum-weak-private-keys/#:%7E:text=To%20explain%20how%20that%20blockchain,of%20atoms%20in%20the%20universe.)

> The the odds of guessing a randomly generated Ethereum private key is
> 1 in 115 quattuorvigintillion. (Or, as a fraction: 1/2^256.) That
> denominator is very roughly around the number of atoms in the
> universe.

(if you have 12-word mnemonic, the fraction is 1/2^128)

So this means the probabilty of guessing a private key is almost 0.

**BUT** if you save your key or mnemonic in your computer or your phone. Someone can still break into your computer or phone and find your mnemonic there. So there's always a chance that the place you saved your mnemonic get hacked. We can now say that the chance of not getting hacked is not 0 . Unfortunately, there is no certain number to declare the probability of your computer ( Or phone or anywhere else you saved your mnemonic) getting hacked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is there a possibility that the private key stored in the metamask will be leaked?

Comment: You're welcome. This can help you. Read all the answers -> [Does metamask store private key on server or anywhere else?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39954/does-metamask-store-private-key-on-server-or-anywhere-else)